# When are the extra levels available?

Tags: mighty-switch-force

Mighty Switch Force was [updated recently with 5 new levels](http://www.wayforward.com/blog/2012/5/22/a-mighty-announcement-from-wayforward.html), I got a prompt to update my version when I entered the eShop but I still see only 16 levels in the game.

Are the extra levels only available after completing the main levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this myself by completing all of the original levels. **The extra levels will be added to your list once you complete all of the original 16** (you don't have to be below par).